# How to use jQuery to process html checkboxes populated from another PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm having trouble to disabled certain checkboxes which populated from another PHP using jQuery. I guess my mistake is coming from `$(document).ready`. Please help, thanks!

PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE user="'.$_POST['user'].'%"');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['user'].'" data-tag="'.$row['tag'].'" />'.$row['user'];
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showResult').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'load_result.php',
            data: { user: $('#userSelect').val() }
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
    });

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tag = $this.data('tag');
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([data-tag*="'+tag+'"])').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([data-tag*="'+tag+'"])').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: show your entire script

Comment: Two things: 1) The if-else at the end of your jQuery code does the same thing in both branches; and 2) You need to move from `mysql_` functions to `mysqli_` or `PDO` and sanitize your parameters before passing them to the database

Comment: @nosthertus sorry, i'm inconvinient to show the entire script.
@AlvaroMontoro (1) my bad, its a typo. (2) i dont think the `mysqli` functions are the cause for my problem though :/

Comment: mysqli is definitely not the cause of this problem, but it's poor programming and a problem in itself. Take it as a piece of advice and not as criticism.

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding your question. What should happen with the checkboxes? when are they populated?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro sorry i didnt mean it, i thought you were saying that my problem was caused by the sanitizing mysqli functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since new elements are being created, after you did event binding you have to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which means bind click event on all checkboxes and new ones.

Your code should look something like this :

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]',function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tag = $this.data('tag');
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([data-tag*="'+tag+'"])').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([data-tag*="'+tag+'"])').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
```

On the past versions you could use `live();` but since 1.7 this is deprecated and you have to use `on()`.

Comment: Spot on man THANKS! can't believe I tried to solve this for so long ;D